# Can't create an element externally in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This line of code works on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q1osexrf/)

```
var skipButton = document.getElementById("skip");
var counter = 10;
var newElement = document.createElement("p");
newElement.innerHTML = "Skip this after 10 seconds";
var id;

skipButton.parentNode.replaceChild(newElement, skipButton);

id = setInterval(function(){
counter--;
    if(counter < 0){
        newElement.parentNode.replaceChild(skipButton, newElement);
        clearInterval(id);
    } else {
        newElement.innerHTML = "You can skip this in " + counter.toString() + "seconds.";
    }
 }, 1000);
```

But when i tried it on my wamp it doesn't work . Why is that . Can someone send some suggestion why it is not working.

Comment: Where is this code in the context of your document? In your jsFiddle it's set to execute in the document's `onload` handler

Comment: they're just in 1 folder namely : splashscreen.js, splashscreen.css, splashscreen.html . is that what you mean by context sir?

Comment: Your javascript needs to either occur after your markup OR needs to be wrapped in a function that waits for the DOM to be loaded.

Comment: @LeeWise what do you mean by that sir?

Comment: No. Where is the `<script>` tag in your document? I'm assuming it's in the `<head>`. See the linked question and answers

Comment: yeah my html is like this ```<html><head><title></title><script src = "splashscreen.js"></script></head>```

Comment: Since your script is being called in the head before your <div id="skip"> then you will need to wrap your js code in a function that waits for it to render:
if(document.readyState === "complete") {
  //Already loaded!
}

Comment: @LeeWise so i should do it like this ```var skipButton = document.getElementById("skip");
var counter = 10;
var newElement = document.createElement("p");
newElement.innerHTML = "Skip this after 10 seconds";
var id;
if(document.readyState ==="complete"){
skipButton.parentNode.replaceChild(newElement, skipButton);

id = setInterval(function(){
 counter--;
  if(counter < 0){
   newElement.parentNode.replaceChild(skipButton, newElement);
   clearInterval(id);
  } else {
   newElement.innerHTML = "You can skip this in " + counter.toString() + "seconds.";
  }
}, 1000);
}```

Comment: You need to put ALL of your current js inside that function. So in my previous comment you would put your code where it says '//Already loaded!'

Comment: @LeeWise  still not working :(

Comment: Can you open the console log and see if there are any errors

Comment: @LeeWise No errors.

Comment: My mistake, try this:
```document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
// Your Code Here
});```

Comment: i already solved it sir thank you . :) i just change my html instead on the head my js script i wrote it down on my body tag